# DynamicCastClassUnconditional with destionationViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to get an instance of my destinationViewController but always get the error of dynamiccastclassunconditional.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier{
        if identifier == "update" {
            var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = endPointList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as NSManagedObject
            var endPointForm : SettingsEndpointCreateViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SettingsEndpointCreateViewController

        }
    }
}
```

endPointForm triggers the error. The ViewController is of Type UITableViewController. What is the issue here?

UPDATE:

I am trying to present the viewController modally. But if I do that I lose the navigation controls. That is why I embedded the SettingsEndpointCreateViewController inside a NavigationController.
Like shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the destination view controller has `UIViewController` type and not `SettingsEndpointCreateViewController`. If you created that vc in interface builder, you probably missed to specify the custom class for it (from the identity inspector)

Comment: Because it presents the SettingsEndpointCreateViewController modally and this controller is embedded inside a navigation controller which the segues are pointing to.

Comment: try setting a breakpoint on that line and inspect what `segue.destinationViewController` actually contains

Comment: You are right about the UIViewController. But I want to contain the Navigation. That is why I did it that way.

Comment: I don't understand... you know it's **not** an instance of `SettingsEndpointCreateViewController`, but you still want to do the downcast

Comment: I dont know how else I can do it. I want to show the next screen modally but without losing the navigation bar.

Comment: You should better explain in your question what you want to achieve. The question itself (and my answer) has nothing to do with what you are saying in the comments above. I suggest to add an update below your original question with some more clarifications about what you are trying to do